# How to get URL of the image source of Google Places API objects

Tags: node.js, web-services, google-places-api, alexa-skills-kit

I'm building an Alexa Skill using Google Places API. I get the response, everything fine, there are up to 20 Objects in the JSON Array, but I cannot find the URLs of the images. E.g. by sending this URL to the API (key is hidden, please replace):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?key=XXX&photoreference=CmRaAAAAnqOWtjVAhP5ExRrR34oklTIR9Z1ILGKl2N4JkfZYWbqJeIKQq_NuBDR5eQx20_UOQvfFwzuaEJIOH-mNjVQwLPLl_1zSANqmNkF0MUiSuDpz0deW1PGzVJeYdKHROLB3EhCkDZjsjed-Z5f63e5p5-E7GhRihV90sb8Ozj3wU2fdzlsbtfFr9Q&maxwidth=720&maxheight=480
```

I am getting the image itself and following Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *  
Access-Control-Expose-Headers → Content-Length  
Alt-Svc →quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35" 
Cache-Control →private, max-age=86400, no-transform 
Content-Disposition → inline;filename="2017-08-26.jpg"  
Content-Length →102419  
Content-Type → image/jpeg  
Date → Sun, 15 Oct 2017 19:11:44 GMT 
ETag → "vac67"  Expires → Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT  
Server → fife  
Vary → Origin  
X-Content-Type-Options → nosniff  
X-XSS-Protection → 1;mode=block
```

Monitoring the network, I've found out that there are two requests:

- The first one if of status "302" (redirected) and the request name is exactly what I sent out via Postman.
- The second request is of status "200" and under "Request URL" I can see the real URL of the image:

  ```
  https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMHPAf26S0Ei4EmUuBlLe131dVLDeYQCoiotHgc=s1600-w720-h480
  ```

Now, how can I get this URL with NodeJS?

Comment: We need more info. Are you using http or express or do you want to use a fetch or xmlhttprequest? in your nodejs?